# $GET outside/parent page

Tags: php, jquery

This may be a bit confusing, but this is what I have so far.

I have a parent page, which uses JQuery.load() to load into it a child php page. This parent page has the url: ***localhost/piproject/roster.php?id=2***

Inside of my child php page, I want to access that `id#`, however `$_GET["id"]` is null because the child page actually has it's own sub-url (not the technical term).

I want to have that child page refresh without affecting the parent page, so I am using `setInterval()` on my function which does the `.load()`. How can I achieve this functionality, and also be able to access the page id?

Comment: could you use $_SESSION

Comment: Interesting, I was actually thinking of that. Although it's a poor choice, it would definitely do the job.

Comment: also I think you can just tak the get id onto the load URL, then echo it to the page in a hidden input so javascript can access it.

Comment: Is the javascript in the child or parent page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print the id into a javascript variable on the parent page.

```
<script>
    var pageId = <?= $_GET['id'] =>;   // integer
    var pageId = "<?= $_GET['id'] =>"; // string
</script>
```